# How to ignore "uTorrent Web app will damage your mac" warning?

Tags: macos, mac, utorrent, macos-catalina

MAC is identifying uTorrent Web App as an malware and restricting me from opening it. Now, I don't care if uTorrent Web contains any malware, I just want to open and use it.

I'm using MacOS Catalina. Thus, can't use uTorrent app for mac, which is 32 bit. That is why I had to install the web app.
I had some download in progress. So, I just want to open the uTorrent web app and continue with the download. Does anyone have any idea?

[image: mac warning]

Comment: "MAC is identifying uTorrent Web App as an malware" -- Try other BitTorret client, for example [qbittorrent](https://www.qbittorrent.org/download.php). Security should be the first concern.

Comment: @Biswapriyo As I said inside the question "I dont care if it contains malware". Maybe I will shift to another client but currently I am in middle of a download and the file size was huge. Can't go through from the top again.

Comment: Look in *System Preferences > Security & Privacy >  General tab*. if uTorrent Web is listed, click "Open Anyway", and if a warning prompt appears click Open.

Comment: @harrymc worked. Provide your answer, I will mark it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an app fails to install because it hasn’t been notarized or is from an
unidentified developer, it will appear in
*System Preferences > Security & Privacy*, under the General tab.
You need to click *Open Anyway* to confirm opening or installing the app.

[image]

If a second warning dialog appears, click *Open*:

[image]

From now on this app is saved as an exception to your security settings,
so that in the future you may open it freely without any warning.

Source: [Safely open apps on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491)

Comment: Oh, 'cmon, this just does not work for uTorrent Web.

Comment: -1, this must not be accepted as a right answer.

Comment: @artuska: You do understand that this worked for the poster, although more than a year ago. You would do better to mark it as "no longer working in 2020".

Answer (score 9):

None of the options above worked on Mac OS with Catalina: 
I went to *finder* >> right click *utorrent web* >> select *get info* >> select *override malware protection*

Comment: +1, this should be the right answer.